# AWS Django Elastic Beanstalk migration error

Tags: mysql, django, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

## Background

I created a website using Django and have it deployed on AWS EB with a MySQL Amazon RDS database. Recently I added a new field to one of the existing models in my `models.py` file. Everything worked fine on my local server (uses local SQLite, not RDS), but when I deployed the new update to EB I get the following error when I visit any page:

```
OperationalError at /
(1054, "Unknown column 'old_model.new_field' in 'field list'")
```

## Question

**What did I do wrong to get the error above and what can I do to fix it?**

`db-migrate.config`:

```
container_commands:
  01_migrate:
    command: "django-admin.py migrate"
    leader_only: true
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: app.settings
```

Comment: Has EB ran any migrations at all?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. When I deploy it runs `django-admin.py migrate` automatically.

Comment: Typically you'd use `manage.py migrate` and even if you think it's running, do you _know_ it's ran? It sounds like it ran the first time because you talk about visiting pages on the site, but it can't have applied that latest migration due to that error.

Comment: I thought it was running because I tried adding some extra commands which errored out during deployment. But I do not know it is running, so if it isn't what can I do to make it run?

Answer (score 0):

Creating a manual migration with `python manage.py makemigrations`, if this doesn't found any new changes in models try the same with your app name and then migrate the DB with `python manage.py migrate`

This should solve your issue. if this doesn't solve your issue, clear all the migrations file the again run `makemigrations`

Comment: No dice. I tried running `python manage.py makemigrations`, then `python manage.py migrate`. I also changed `django-admin.py migrate` to `python manage.py migrate` in db-migrate.config. I then ran `eb deploy` to redeploy the site but the error persisted.

Comment: have you removed previous migrations? make sure that migration files are removed.
then try makemigrations and migrate.

Comment: Yes, I have, all that was left was __init__.py.

Comment: does this happen only in the beanstalk, what about local?

Comment: The local server works fine, but it uses a local SQLite DB instead of the MySQL RDS DB that the production server uses.

Answer (score 0):

- I suspect migrations are not running properly.
- Create an EC2 instance and try to run migrations on it connected to RDS instead of local sqlite DB.
- Make sure your EC2 instance and RDS are on the same VPC.
- After that deploy your app to EB.

Comment: This should fix your problem. If this didn't solve your problem discuss here.